# How do I know which package to install?

Tags: nvidia, 14.10, overclocking

Could you please help me with installing `nvclock` and `nvclock-gtk` on Ubuntu 14.10?

I used to use Arch Linux and there everything was simple: We had two repository, official and Arch User Repository, where was all that was needed. But due to some reasons, I have been compelled to install Ubuntu.

So now I wonder where and how could I install the `NVClock` utility on my PC. I have already installed the proprietary `nvidia-304` drivers with `nvidia-current` package.

Answer (score 2):

The command to *look what to install* is:

```
apt-cache search nvclock
```

this gives as output:

```
nvclock - Overclock an NVIDIA card
nvclock-gtk - Overclock an NVIDIA card (GTK+ interface)
nvclock-qt - Overclock an NVIDIA card (Qt interface)
```

So the command to install `nvclock` and `nvclock-gtk` is:

```
apt-get install nvclock nvclock-gtk
```